# Using command line debugger in cygwin

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to debug a crash in my program running on cygwin. The program has been compiled and linked using visual studio 12 tools. A trial license for the full vs12 version has been installed so presumably we have access to the vs12 debugger. I've never used this before, I'm more familiar with command line tools in linux like gdb or lldb on osx. It doesn't seem that gdb is installed on our windows machines and I don't have admin access. I'd like to simply run a backtrace on the program at the point at which it fails. Can anyone give a quick start for using the debugging tools on cygwin/windows? I've tried the following

$devenv /debugexe /winsame/swsides/myexec 'program-options'

A microsoft visual studio window opens up, but again I'm not clear on where to start. It would be great if there was a simple command line interface.

Comment: With Visual Studio you usually debug from within the IDE. Launch the IDE, load your program and debug your way to an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. We're compiling/tests using the visual studio tools completely with our own (very large and complicated) build system. We don't use the IDE at all. Sorry for being such a VS newbie. Can I assume that running through the IDE is the usual matter of making obvious menu choices and stumbling through to a solution?

Comment: Yup! Probably the hardest change from being used to gdb (pdb etc.) to VS is that it's a full working IDE and is best debugged there.